# React array map is duplicating array inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

Creating a movie application and showtimes are embedded in an array of objects inside an array of movie objects. The times are duplicating and rendering out the movie 3 times if there are 3 showtimes or 5 if there are 5 showtimes. Trying to only render one copy of the MovieShow component for each movie and not showtime.

movies is the list of movies from the server and date is the state to switch between different showtimes/dates

Movie Data:

```
module.exports = [
  {
    title: "Inception",
    year: "2010",
    rated: "PG-13",
    released: "16 Jul 2010",
    runtime: "148 min",
    genre: "Action, Adventure, Sci-Fi",
    director: "Christopher Nolan",
    writer: "Christopher Nolan",
    actors: "Leonardo DiCaprio, Joseph Gordon-Levitt, Elliot Page",
    plot: "Dom Cobb is a skilled thief, the absolute best in the dangerous art of extraction, stealing valuable secrets from deep within the subconscious during the dream state, when the mind is at its most vulnerable. Cobb's rare ability has made him a coveted player in this treacherous new world of corporate espionage, but it has also made him an international fugitive and cost him everything he has ever loved. Now Cobb is being offered a chance at redemption. One last job could give him his life back but only if he can accomplish the impossible, inception. Instead of the perfect heist, Cobb and his team of specialists have to pull off the reverse: their task is not to steal an idea, but to plant one. If they succeed, it could be the perfect crime. But no amount of careful planning or expertise can prepare the team for the dangerous enemy that seems to predict their every move. An enemy that only Cobb could have seen coming.",
    country: "United States, United Kingdom",
    awards: "Won 4 Oscars. 159 wins & 220 nominations total",
    poster:
      "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjAxMzY3NjcxNF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTI5OTM0Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
    imdbRating: "8.8",
    imdbID: "tt1375666",
    shows: [
      {
        date: "12th June",
        startTime: "14.30pm",
      },
      {
        date: "12th June",
        startTime: "18.30pm",
      },
      {
        date: "12th June",
        startTime: "20.15pm",
      },
      {
        date: "13th June",
        startTime: "22.45pm",
      },
    ],
```

MovieList component:

```
import useMovieContext from "../../hooks/useMovieContext";
import MovieShow from "./MovieShow";

export default function MovieList() {
  const { movies, date } = useMovieContext();

  const renderedList = movies?.map((movie) =>
    movie.shows.map((show) => {
      if (show.date === date) {
        return <MovieShow key={movie.imdbID} movie={movie} link="showtimes" />;
      }
    })
  );

  return <div>{renderedList}</div>;
}
```

MovieShow component:

```
import "../../CSS/Movies/MovieShow.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import MovieTimes from "../MoviePage/MovieTimes";
import useMovieContext from "../../hooks/useMovieContext";

export default function MovieShow({ movie, link }) {
  const { date } = useMovieContext();

  const renderedList = movie.shows?.map((show) => {
    if (show.date === date) {
      return <MovieTimes show={show} movie={movie} />;
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="movie-container">
      <img className="movie-poster" src={movie.poster} alt="" />
      <div className="movie-details">
        <h1>{movie.title}</h1>
        <h2>Rated: {movie.rated}</h2>
        <h3>Running Time: {movie.runtime}</h3>
        <h3>Date: {new Date().toDateString().substring(4)}</h3>
        <Link state={{ movie: movie }} to={`/${link}/${movie._id}`}>
          <button>More Details</button>
        </Link>
        <div className="movie-times-list">{renderedList}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Tried mapping over the shows array but its duplicating the MovieShow component for each movie.

Tried filtering but this will not work as objects cannot be filtered

Comment: Can you show the `MovieShow` component?

Comment: Actually, I think I see the issue.  ` if (show.date === date) {`  In your data, there are three days with `12th June`, so it would list all three of those if date is `12th June`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently structured to display a record every time the condition matches:

```
movie.shows.map((show) => {
  if (show.date === date) {
    return <MovieShow key={movie.imdbID} movie={movie} link="showtimes" />;
  }
})
```

That is, if `date` is `"12th June"` then in the data shown this will match on 3 records and show the component 3 times.

It sounds like `.map()` is the wrong tool for the inner condition here.  You don't want to project the array, you just want to check if a value exists in the array.  Perhaps something like this:

```
const renderedList = movies?.map((movie) => {
  if (movie.shows.some((show) => show.date === date)) {
    return <MovieShow key={movie.imdbID} movie={movie} link="showtimes" />;
  }
});
```

Comment: I've just tested this and it works perfectly now, thank you very much!